# Pytest delete db after tests

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I have a test suite in pytest-django and I want to create a database at the start of the test and then delete the same as soon a test is completed in order to simulate the scenario without keeping a huge chunk of data.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into `tearDownClass`. You can reset the DB there. Or in your pytest config.

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of a [fixture teardown](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code) using the `yield` statement instead of `return`. This allows you to setup database, return any data if you want and then perform any cleanup. If you want this to be performed for every test regardless of a test function declaring the use of the fixture or not, set `autouse` to `True`.

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=False)
def db():
    # Setup DB here

    # Yield some data, database connection or nothing at all
    yield None

    # Delete DB here when the test ends

def test_something(db):
    # Database will be ready here and db will contain whatever
    # db() function yields. With autouse=True you don't need to
    # set the db fixture as the function param.
    pass
```

Comment: "# Delete DB here when the test ends" - can you show how to do it ?

Comment: @Vadim That really depends on the database that you use and the Python package that you use to access it.

Comment: I am not deleting database yet, but I am deleting objects after yield. When tests fail, they are not deleted. I'm not sure about the whole database.

Comment: in this example, should this db be passed to each tests? What would happen if tests fail or error?

Comment: _In this example, should this db be passed to each tests?_ That depends on your circumstances. If your test needs to work with an object that `db` fixture yields, then you need to se it as a test function argument. If the fixture needs to setup/teardown database before/after each test but you don't need what it yields, then it's better to set `@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)` and you don't need to declare it.  _What would happen if tests fail or error?_ The teardown part after fixture's `yield` should continue anyway.